# Error in mysql fetch error in php

Tags: php, mysql, html

Hi 
when i run my code this proplem apper

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.5.0\www\List.php on line 28
```

this is my code

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<html>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='Style.css'>
<title>Registration</title>
<body>



<?php
$S=$_POST['Sec'];
echo "<H4>Web Development a</H4>";
echo "<b>CS  <br>Registration Page </b><br><br><br><br>";
echo "<b>This is the students lists who are registered in section $S: <br><br>";
echo "<table border=1 width=50%><tr><td width='6'></td><td bgcolor='#E66C2C' width='150'><b><center><font 
color='#FFFFFF'>Name</center></td><td bgcolor='#E66C2C' width='100'><b><center><font 
color='#FFFFFF'>ID</center></td>". "<td bgcolor='#E66C2C' width='100'><b><center><font color='#FFFFFF'>E-Mail</center></td></tr>";


include('con_db.php');

$sql = "select * from students where Sec=$S ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$i=0;

while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$i++;
echo "<tr><td bgcolor='#eae5a7' width='6'>";
            echo "<b><center>".$i."</center><br>";
echo"</td>";
echo "<td  width='150'>";
            echo "<b><center>".$r[Fname]."</center><br>" ;
echo "</td>";
echo "<td width='100'>";
            echo "<b><center>".$r[ID]."</center><br>" ;
echo "</td>";
echo "<td width='100'>";
            echo "<b><center>".$r[mail]."</center><br>" ;
echo "</td></tr>";
echo "</font>";
}

echo"</table>";
echo "<form name='form' method='post' action='Registration_List.php'>";
?>

<br><br><center><input type='submit' id='send' value='Back'  style="color: #FFFFFF; background-color: #E66C2C; border-width: 1; border-style: 1" ></form>

<?php
echo "<form name='form' method='post' action='ass1.php'>";
?>
<input type='submit' id='send' value='Home Page'  style="color: #FFFFFF; background-color: #E66C2C; border-width: 1; border-style: 1"></form></center></td></tr></table>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't forget that you can mark an answer as accepted. You only need to click on the *tick* icon. That shows appreciation for the effort.

Comment: Homework: Try typing `<script>top.location="http://www.google.com"</script>` in your form and, once you fix the SQL query, `' OR '1'='1`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Comment: `mysql_query` has been deprecated since version 5.5.0. Better to use `mysqli_query` that supports prepared statements and therefore is much more secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rewrite so this:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$i=0;

while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
```

becomes this:

```
if($result = mysql_query($sql)){
    $i=0;

   while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   ...
   }
} else {
   //do something with mysql_error()
}
```

Comment: while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
if ($r["Sec"]==1 && $s != 1)
$s--;
if ($r["Sec"]==2 && $s != 1)
$u--;
if ($r["Sec"]==3 && $s != 1)
$m--;
if ($r["Sec"]==4 && $s != 1 )
$t--;
if ($r["Sec"]==5 && $s != 1)
$w--;
}
?>

Answer (score 1):

Your `mysql_query($sql)` call is probably returning `false`. You need to see if your script managed to connect to your mysql server

From the manual : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

```
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: +1, but a query error would also cause a false return, so check the query as well as the connection.  a swift echo type call to `mysql_error()` after `mysql_query()` should do the trick.

Comment: @Jeff Parker  I was actually editing my post when you commented :)

Comment: No problem ... and you've already had your +1.  Don't eat it all at once :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically Error like `Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given..` means that your query result is wrong. `mysql_query` instead of returning result returns `false`, which means your query is wrong.

Simple check what's wrong using:

```
$sql = "select * from students where Sec=$S ";
#                               V ADDED
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error() );
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means you had an error in your sql, make sure you escape it before using it because you might become victim of sql injection.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE seconds=%d";
$sql = sprintf($sql,mysql_real_escape_string($S));
```

make sure you have the correct data in $S;

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Error: ".mysql_error());
```

and this way you will know what is your exact error.